# MSXML2.ServerHTTP in Coldfusion 8 fails to post data

Tags: forms, com, coldfusion, serverxmlhttp

In trying to work around the buggy `<cfhttp>` SSL implementation, I switched to using COM and MSXML2.ServerHTTP directly. Unfortunately the POST data fails to arrive at the destination page. GET works, but I'd rather not use it, since I have no idea if the request urls are logged and I don't want to pass sensitive data if I can help it. (Am I worrying too much?)

My problem is similar to this one: http://objectmix.com/xml-soap/87408-sending-post-variables-using-msxml2-serverxmlhttp-3-0-a.html

Here's my code:

```
<cfset querystring = "?CustomerID=#CustomerID#&OrderDelRecipient=#OrderDelRecipient#&OrderCompany=#OrderCompany#&OrderTelephone=#OrderTelephone#&OrderNotes=#OrderNotes#&OrderDelStreet=#OrderDelStreet#&OrderDelCity=#OrderDelCity#&OrderDelState=#OrderDelState#&OrderDelZip=#OrderDelZip#">
<cfobject type="COM" action="Create" name="objSrvHTTP" class="MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0">
    <cfset urlstring = "http://www.pascaltechnologies.com/saveorder.cfm">
<cfset temp = objSrvHTTP.open("post", urlstring, false)>
<cfset temp = objSrvHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-
urlencoded")>
<cfset temp = objSrvHTTP.send("#querystring#")>
<cfset FileContent = objSrvHTTP.responsetext>
<cfoutput>
    #filecontent#
</cfoutput>
```

When I check for the Form vars on the **called** page (saveorder.cfm)

```
<cfif Not IsDefined("CustomerID") OR NOT IsNumeric(CustomerID)>
    ERR 609 - INVALID PARAMETERS PASSED.
    <cfabort>
</cfif>
```

they are empty, so the above code gets triggered.

Is this because I need to copy the response to the form var? e.g. `<cfset FORM.CustomerID = objSrvHTTP.CustomerID>` (You'd think it wouldn't be necessary since it isn't needed with GET.) Or am I simply not implementing something correctly?

Comment: You know you don't have to assign everything to temporary variables like `<cfset temp = objSrvHTTP.send("#querystring#")>` - you can just do `<cfset objSrvHTTP.send("#querystring#")>`

Comment: That example you link to creates a name=value list - `DataToSend = "test=booyah"
objXMLDoc.send(DataToSend)` but you construct a query string with a leading **?** - `<cfset querystring = "?CustomerID=... objSrvHTTP.send("#querystring#")`

Comment: I tried using the query string without the question mark, and got the same result. A query string **is** a name=value list, it's just in string format and delimited with ampersands. And I was using the temp var to see if the method returned anything (I left that code out of my example).

Comment: It works fine for me, once I removed the line break in the `content-type` value. Add a few `cfdump`'s at the top of the page to view what *is* being sent. ie `FORM`, `URL` and `GetHTTPRequestData`

Comment: One thing to try is to ensure you're adding URLEncodedFormat when building the query params as they need to be encoded.  Otherwise &=and other characters will interfere with the name/value pairs.
<cfset querystring = "?CustomerID=#URLEncodedFormat(CustomerID)#&OrderDelRecipient=#URLEncodedFormat(OrderDelRecipient)#......">